# How to mount a partition inside encrypted lvm inside a disk image?

Tags: linux, mount, lvm, disk-encryption, disk-image

On my previous computer, I had my / /home and swap inside an encrypted lvm, and outside the lvm I had the /boot and /boot/efi. I then created an image. I *think* I did like this: `dd if=/dev/sda of=lvm.img bs=4M` but I don't remember. I could check it in .bash_history, if I just could decrypt the image first...

I have been trying to follow this guide: https://gist.github.com/talaj/721d50791e95ea585316ea0571822fa7

First I examined the file:

```
# file lvm.img 
lvm.img: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x0,0,2), end-CHS 

(0x3ff,254,63), startsector 1, 250069679 sectors, extended partition table (last)

# fdisk -lu lvm.img
Disk lvm.img: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 9FEF2EAF-1AE7-47B1-A446-7B3EBCB24A54

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
lvm.img1      2048   3907583   3905536   1.9G EFI System
lvm.img2   3907584   7813119   3905536   1.9G Linux filesystem
lvm.img3   7813120 250068991 242255872 115.5G Linux LVM
```

So it certainly looks like it contains what it should. How should I do to view the partitions inside `lvm.img3` and mount them?

I started with this:

```
# kpartx -av lvm.img 
add map loop0p1 (253:3): 0 3905536 linear 7:0 2048
add map loop0p2 (253:4): 0 3905536 linear 7:0 3907584
add map loop0p3 (253:5): 0 242255872 linear 7:0 7813120
```

Continued with this:

```
# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/mapper/loop0p3 mylvm
```

Hmmmm? I did not need to enter passphrase? Whatever. Contiuning the guide.

```
# vgscan
  Reading volume groups from cache.
  Found volume group "fedora" using metadata type lvm2
  Found volume group "fedora_desktop-ld77fgg" using metadata type lvm2

# vgchange -a y fedora_desktop--ld77fgg
  Volume group "fedora_desktop--ld77fgg" not found
  Cannot process volume group fedora_desktop--ld77fgg
```

And now I'm stuck...

I'm using Fedora, but if it matters I could switch to another distribution.

**EDIT:**

As telcoM pointed out in an answer I had made a very silly mistake, and I don't understand how. Nevertheless I still have problems. I corrected my last command by changing the double dash to a single dash:

```
# vgchange -a y fedora_desktop-ld77fgg
  4 logical volume(s) in volume group "fedora_desktop-ld77fgg" now active
```

And then

```
# mount /dev/fedora_desktop-ld77fgg/03 /tmp/hej
mount: /tmp/hej: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  Found volume group "fedora_desktop-ld77fgg" using metadata type lvm2

# vgchange -a y fedora_desktop--ld77fgg
```

When the `vgscan` command tells you the name of the VG, you can use it as is with the `vgchange` command - you don't have to double the dashes.

> A mini-summary of Logical Volume Manager (LVM):
>
> - In order to use LVM, you can initialize partitions or entire disks as LVM Physical Volumes (PVs)...
> - ... and you use one or more PVs to create a Volume Group (VG), which is basically treated as an uniform pile of raw storage space, which you can then freely slice into...
> - ..one or more LVM Logical Volumes (LVs). A single LV can span more than one PV: even if it's made out of many disjoint pieces, a filesystem placed on it will see it as a single logically continuous unit of storage. And a LV can be migrated from one place to another within the VG, *while the LV is mounted and in use.*

You'll need to do that only with *pathnames*: since the format is `/dev/mapper/<VG name>-<LV name>`, any unmodified single dashes in the pathname would make it ambiguous: any program processing the name would not know which dash is part of the name and which one separates the `<VG name>` and the `<LV name>` parts from each other.

---

It looks like you thought the order of containers was:

```
disk -> partition -> LUKS wrapper -> PV -> LV -> filesystem
```

but the lack of need to specify the passphrase when trying to run `cryptsetup luksOpen` and the error message when trying to mount `/dev/fedora_desktop-ld77fgg/03` suggest that the actual order of things is:

```
disk -> partition -> PV -> LV -> LUKS wrapper -> filesystem
```

To confirm this, see if your `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/mapper/loop0p3 mylvm` actually created a `/dev/mapper/mylvm` device or not. I suspect it might have not done anything at all.

Instead, you should now do:

```
# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/fedora_desktop-ld77fgg/03 myfs
<answer the passphrase prompt>
# mount /dev/mapper/myfs /tmp/hej
```

Comment: Thank you, but that did not solve the problem. See my updated question.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly.

Comment: For future readers, I think it would be good if you explained the acronyms VG, LV and PV.

Comment: Done. How's that?

Comment: Perfect. I'd upvote again if I could.